# How can i split the text file in dictonary in python

Tags: python, centos, urllib2

I have this text file

```
application/andrew-inset                        ez
application/applixware                          aw
application/atom+xml                            atom
application/atomcat+xml                         atomcat
application/atomsvc+xml                         atomsvc
application/ccxml+xml                           ccxml
application/cdmi-capability                     cdmia
application/cdmi-container                      cdmic
image/jpeg                                      jpeg jpg jpe
```

and i want to convert in to python dictonary of key value pairs.
How can i do that.

I am also confused in case of multiple values how should i do.

I want to get the the file extension from the mimetypes

so basically in case of multiple value i want to get the first one.

e,g

`mydict['image/jpeg']` should return `jpeg`

This is what i treid

```
import shlex
f = open("mimetypes.txt","r")
mydict = dict()
for line in f:
        k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())
        mydict[k.strip()] =  v.strip()

f.close()
f2 = open("mimetest.txt","w")
f2.write(mydict)
f2.close()
```

and i get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makedict.py", line 5, in <module>
    k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: This is pretty simple. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Per your update, you are very close - the issue is because of this line:

```
k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())
```

As you know, it works fine for any element with two items, but the problem comes when you have more than one. For example:

```
In [1]: import shlex

In [2]: line = 'one two'

In [3]: k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())

In [4]: print k, v
one two

In [5]: line = 'one two three'

In [6]: k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/<ipython console> in <module>()

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What is happening is that you are trying to assign two variables using a list of three items, which will give you that error. One thing you could do in your code is to limit the returned list to return only two items by doing something like:

```
In [7]: line = 'one two three'

In [8]: k,v = shlex.split(line.strip())[:2]

In [9]: print k, v
one two
```

---

The general idea is that you create a dictionary, open the file and then on each line, strip the trailing newline, split on whitespace and take the first two elements of the resulting list:

```
In [5]: d = {}

In [6]: with open('mime.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         mime, val = line.strip().split()[:2]
   ...:         d[mime] = val
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [7]: d
Out[7]: 
{'application/andrew-inset': 'ez',
 'application/applixware': 'aw',
 'application/atom+xml': 'atom',
 'application/atomcat+xml': 'atomcat',
 'application/atomsvc+xml': 'atomsvc',
 'application/ccxml+xml': 'ccxml',
 'application/cdmi-capability': 'cdmia',
 'application/cdmi-container': 'cdmic',
 'image/jpeg': 'jpeg'}

In [8]: d['image/jpeg']
Out[8]: 'jpeg'
```

And if you need to store all of the items, you can do this:

```
In [1]: d = {}

In [2]: with open('mime.txt', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         line = line.strip().split()
   ...:         d[line[0]] = line[1:]
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [3]: d
Out[3]: 
{'application/andrew-inset': ['ez'],
 'application/applixware': ['aw'],
 'application/atom+xml': ['atom'],
 'application/atomcat+xml': ['atomcat'],
 'application/atomsvc+xml': ['atomsvc'],
 'application/ccxml+xml': ['ccxml'],
 'application/cdmi-capability': ['cdmia'],
 'application/cdmi-container': ['cdmic'],
 'image/jpeg': ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpe']}
```

This includes all of the MIME types, so if you just want the first one you can call the first element of a given type's value:

```
In [4]: d['image/jpeg'][0]
Out[4]: 'jpeg
```

Comment: It is pretty clear that the OP didn't even try to do this themselves, you shouldn't just hand out answers like this.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I've seen differing opinions on this, and I usually fall on the side of providing any direction I can and hoping the OP gets something useful from it. I know far less than most people on this site, so I definitely know what it is like to be stuck somewhere and have no idea where to go. It may be simple to some people, but to somebody just learning it may be a little more difficult.

Comment: I have tried something , i will post above to see where i am wrong

Comment: @RocketDonkey I definitely understand where you are coming from, it is just that I have seen in the past that just handing out answers makes people more reliant on sites like this, which isn't really such a bad thing I guess. But self-reliance is a really overlooked attribute of a programmer/developer/whatever; figuring it out on your own will make you more likely to not make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: @RocketDonkey But I can see now that they actually did make an attempt, so my comment is null anyway.

Comment: I tried that and now i get this `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I think we're coming from the same place though :) I 100% agree with on some of the more blatant cases (the 'Yeah, code this for me'-type stuff) - I guess I'm kind of a softie in that I'll default to answering if I see somebody confused (but will happily ignore in the aforementioned cases because I agree, those are super annoying).

Comment: Thanks buddy , i solved it. there was one empty line at the end of file

Comment: @user19140477031 Do you have any empty lines in your file? That will cause that error. Try removing any blank lines and seeing if that gets you to the next step.

Comment: @user19140477031 Ha, beat me to the punch :) Good luck with everything. Also, if you're curious, take a look at the `with` statement (http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example looks like a decent primer). It is a good habit to get into when opening/closing files as it handles things like closing for you.

Comment: @RocketDonkey . whats the diff between opening file with `rb` and `r`.

Comment: @user19140477031 `rb` opens a file for reading in binary mode, it is usually used for read data on of 'binaries' or 'executables'. `r` is used for reading general text files. This is a general description, I am not sure of the python specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be this:

```
dic = {}
file =  open("filename","r")
contents = file.readlines()
for content in contents:
    value = filter(lambda a: a !='',content.split(" "))
    dic[value[0]] = value[1]
file.close()
print dic['image/jpeg']
```

We are splitting each line by " " and then removing any '' in the list. Then we are assigning the dictionary with the values.